# Efficient way to query multiple documents of Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm storing data to cosmos DB like below, and I want to get the latest data for each index.
The number of indexes is variable and at least 10.

(Simplified document)

```
{
    "receivedTime": "2021-06-11T01:48:02.751Z",
    "source": "server",
    "data": {
        "index": "1",
        "value": "my data"
    },
    "id": "c10ef6dc-53a6-40e0-84d1-551e508d0427",
}
```

Currently, I'm querying the number of indexes and displaying the results of each.

(Only `c.data.index = '<index>'` is different, and others same.)

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.source = 'server' AND c.data.index = '1' ORDER BY c._ts DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1,
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.source = 'server' AND c.data.index = '2' ORDER BY c._ts DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1,
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.source = 'server' AND c.data.index = '3' ORDER BY c._ts DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1,
...
```

But as the number of indexes increases, there is a delay.

Is there any way to query them all at once?

Is there any more efficient way to query multiple documents?

I'm using Node.js SDK.

Comment: Do you have an expectation about how recent the results should be? If so one thing to try is a simple query for all newer than some recent point in time, then pick out the items you want from the result set.

Comment: @NoahStahl The documents for each index stored randomly.. So I think the simple query is difficult, but I'll try. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `SELECT c.data.index,max(c._ts) as _ts FROM c group by c.data.index`  but it can't return *

Comment: @TinyWang I tried query but took a long time and the request charge increased. (about 200,000 RUs) Could a large number of documents be the cause?

Comment: I don't the reason, I never met such a large data target QAQ..... @NoahStahl Could you give some advice sir? I knew you an expert in Cosmosdb. Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to a complex query is to created a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view) that will make this operation simple and efficient. If it is a matter of knowing the latest item for each `index` value, we could create a separate container named `LatestByIndex` and use the change feed to keep this populated with a copy of or reference to the latest item for each index value.

To facilitate efficient reads, the `LatestByIndex` items could use the associated `index` value as their `id`. Then finding the latest for index `x` can be done by a point read against `id` `x`. The item could be a copy or a reference to the original item.

The implementation would be a change feed processor that overwrites the item in `LatestByIndex` each time a change in the main container is observed. You may also want a complementary maintenance job that periodically refreshes the latest info as a backup sanity check against the change feed sync.

Comment: Ok.. maybe need to change the document structure to use the method. I'll try. Thanks for the advice.